# Log file created but not being written to

Tags: logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have read every answer related to this question and nothing has helped me. This is my Web.config file (I use log4net in my WCF service)

(Only the relevant section)

```xml
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>

  <!-- Log4Net -->
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="All" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>

    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="logs\server.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] [%property{ip}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

The log file is being created but nothing is being written to it. I have read an answer that said it could be due to not providing a layout pattern, but I am providing that. I am watching for changes:

```cs
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
namespace Foo
{
    class Bar : IBar {
        //..
    }
}
```

I have been struggling for over an hour now and can't find anything that helped. I tried tracing log4net messages but there is no error (nothing being written to the trace file). Can anyone see anything wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Do you have anything setup for log4net in your AssemblyInfo file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the level to all upper-case:

```
<root>
   <level value="ALL" />
   <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
</root>
```

See [Why are all my log4net levels false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658070/why-are-all-my-log4net-levels-false)